# Alfa AWUS036ACH Adapter suddenly not working after successful driver install

Tags: uninstall, realtek-wireless, software-uninstall, dkms, alfa-wireless

Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The Alfa AWUS036ACH didn't work out of the box with Ubuntu, so I Googled around and found a shell script that got it to work. It worked fine for about two weeks and then suddenly stopped working.

Here is the shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Shell script to set up drivers for Alfa AWUS036ACH
# You must have an internet connection.

# update your repositories
apt-get update

# install dkms if it isn't already
apt-get install dkms

# change directory to /usr/src
cd /usr/src

# if you have any other drivers installed,remove them like so:
rm -r rtl8812AU-4.3.22/

# get latest driver from github
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

# move into downloaded driver folder
cd rtl8812au/

# update files in working tree to match files in the index
git checkout --track remotes/origin/v4.3.21

# make drivers
make

# move into parent directory
cd ..

# debugging
dkms status

# rename file for use with dkms
mv rtl8812au/ rtl8812au-4.3.22

# build drivers
dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.3.22

# install drivers
dkms install -m rtl8812au -v 4.3.22

# debugging
lsmod

# summon new interface from the depths of the kernel
modprobe 8812au

# wifi interface should now appear.
ip link
```

The adapter worked just fine for about two weeks and then one day it suddenly stops working or being detected by my OS. Neither `iwconfig` nor `ifconfig` will show it. Just to check that it wasn't an issue with the Alfa adapter itself, I plugged it in to a Windows PC and it worked just fine. Please help me get it working again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experience this on Ubuntu 19.04 whenever I perform an update.

I found [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2361347&p=13650231#post13650231) for fixing a kink in the `dkms.conf` file that instructs how to rebuild the wifi driver upon kernel updates.

```
sudo vim /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/dkms.conf
```

Find the line starting with `MAKE` (or possibly `MAKE[0]`), e.g.:

```
MAKE="'make' all"
```

Replace with:

```
MAKE="'make' all KVER=${kernelver}"
```

Save and exit editor. Then remove and rebuild the adapter for the current kernel:

```
sudo dkms remove -m rtl8812au -v 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg -k $(uname -r)
sudo dkms install -m rtl8812au -v 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg -k $(uname -r)
```

**Alternatively**, a *quick and dirty workaround* is to simply remove and reinstall the driver after each upgrade:

```
sudo apt purge rtl8812au-dkms && sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms
```